# Как зовут автора самого популярного текста среди frontend разработчиков, и особенно UX дизайнеров? Есть зацепка, что имя автора - Марк

Tags: frontend, ux, имена

Как зовут автора самого популярного текста среди frontend разработчиков, и особенно UX дизайнеров? Есть зацепка, что имя автора - Марк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Называется это `Lorem ipsum`, автор исходного текста - Марк Туллий Цицерон, но затем этот текст изменили.

[Ссылка на вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum), там всё подробнее расписано.